# Maximum length value in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table and I´d like to know what is the maximum lengh value that exist on the field "phone_number" and email_address.

I want to know if there exist any value that was entered that is greater than the allowed.

This is my query:

```
    SELECT
    hp.party_name                              
  , hca.account_number
  , hca.cust_account_id                        
 -- , hcsu.LOCATION customer_site_name
  , hcas.cust_acct_site_id                     
  , hcp.phone_number
  , hcp.email_address
  , hl.address1
  , hl.address2
  , hl.address3
  , hl.address4
  , hl.city
  , hl.province
  , hl.postal_code
  , hcas.status                                
  , DECODE( hcas.attribute5, 'PUP', 'Y', 'N' ) 
  , hca.status                                 
FROM apps.hz_cust_accounts hca
INNER JOIN apps.hz_cust_acct_sites_all hcas ON hca.cust_account_id = hcas.cust_account_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_party_sites hps ON hcas.party_site_id = hps.party_site_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_locations hl ON hps.location_id = hl.location_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_parties hp ON hps.party_id = hp.party_id
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            owner_table_id
          , max(case when contact_point_type = 'PHONE' then phone_number end) phone_number
          , max(case when contact_point_type = 'EMAIL' then email_address end) email_address
        FROM hz_contact_points
        WHERE status = 'A'
        AND primary_flag = 'Y'
        AND owner_table_name = 'HZ_PARTY_SITES'
        AND contact_point_type IN ('EMAIL','PHONE')
        GROUP BY 
            owner_table_id
    ) hcp ON hcas.party_site_id = hcp.owner_table_id 
WHERE hcas.status = 'A'
AND hps.status = 'A'
AND hca.status = 'A'
AND hca.account_number = ''
;
```

Comment: Add some example data. What do the entries you are looking at look like, and what do you want them to look like?

Comment: @SandPiper i want to know what is the maximum lengh value,i man, for example: if there exist one single field that contains 2 emails or 3 emails

Comment: Check out this below link:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361761/find-the-length-of-the-longest-row-in-a-column-in-oracle

Comment: How is the maximum allowed value defined? If `hz_contact_points.phone_number` is defined as `varchar2(20)`, for example, then by definition no value can be longer than that, so I'm not sure which values you are looking for.

Comment: *"if there exist one single field that contains 2 emails or 3 emails"* Eh? That's very different from finding the maximum length of a column. You probably need to post some sample data which illustrates the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Maybe something like this could help: [OracleDataReader.GetSchemaTable Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.getschematable?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - I agree the question is not the clearest but there's nothing to suggest the OP is using dot net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum length of a field(s):

```
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(email_address)), MAX(LENGTH(phone_number)) FROM hz_contact_points
```

No group by is needed because you're aggregating the whole set. Note that this tells you the longest data known (eg it will return 72) but it tells you nothing else. You would then have to query again to find rows where this length was the case:

```
SELECT * 
FROM hz_contact_points 
WHERE LENGTH(email_address) = 72
```

It might be easier to look at eg the top 10 rows ordered by email length descending:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM hz_contact_points 
  ORDER BY LENGTH(email_address) DESC
) a
WHERE rownum <= 10
```

(If you're on oracle12c+ you can do away with the outer query and write `FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY` )

Rows that have more than one email address:

```
SELECT * 
FROM hz_contact_points 
WHERE email_address LIKE '%@%@%'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to find the rows that have the maximum field length in given field of a table, then try the following query.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE LENGTH(FIELD_NAME) =
(
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(FIELD_NAME))
FROM TABLE_NAME
)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I tried your query but it is not working, take a look:
https://imgur.com/a/zR1SoBa

Comment: @programming_amazing you are missing a closing bracket in MAX(LENGTH(FIELD_NAME))